# How can I update a data table from an apps script?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have data in a Google Spreadsheet that I would like to add to a data table in Google Map Engine.  Related to this, I have two separate questions:

1. Is there any way to do that with an apps script in the spreadsheet?
2. I have looked at the [Server to Server Authentication (service
   accounts)](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/oauth/serviceaccount) help page a little.  Will I need to set that (or some
   such thing) up to work with my apps script, or is the fact that it
   is my spreadsheet and my map enough to authenticate the script by
   itself?  If I do need to set that up, where can I find sample
   JavaScript code to accomplish the tasks they have shown in their
   sample code on the help page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote:

> You can create and populate a new table by uploading data files
>   through the API

[Table Upload](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/table-upload)

Quote:

> To upload a file, send a POST request to the following URL

[Upload Table Files](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/table-upload#upload_table_files)

You can make a POST request with Apps Script using urlFetchApp:

[urlFetchApp.fetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))

Scroll down one or two screens in that documentation to see the parameters for `urlFetchApp.fetch`

There are various ways you could trigger the Apps Script to run.  You could add a custom drop down menu to your spreadsheet that ran the data upload when the user choose a menu item.

[Custom Menus in Google Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)

The Apps Script can be bound to your Google Sheet.  So, I'm quite sure this can be done.

Comment: Okay, thanks! This looks way easier than periodically updating the take from an external Google Site when a visitor was on the page (the old method I was trying to use)!